# How to get specificaly array with Vue and json

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a json that I am iterating but I want to occupy only the last array that is shown in the iteration:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  commentsToShow: 1,
  json : [
   {
         "date_en":"Wed 26 Aug",
         "date_es":"Mie 26 Agosto",
         "release":[
            {
               "release_en": "Embed to your website",
               "release_es": "Insertar en tu sitio web",
            },
            {
              "release_en": "Multiple memberships",
              "release_es": "Múltiples Membresías",
            }
         ]
   }
],
},
  methods: {

  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="j in json">
      <div v-for="k in j">
        {{k}}
     </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
<a @click="commentsToShow += 1" class="link new">see more</a>
</div>
```

I want to show only : `[ { "release_en": "Embed to your website", "release_es": "Insertar en tu sitio web" }, { "release_en": "Multiple memberships", "release_es": "Múltiples Membresías" } ]`

Because i need something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/mefhk2rv/5/

Comment: Based on what logic? Are you looking for `{{ json[0].release }}`?

Comment: @str i update the question, why i need that

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically select which values to render via HTML, in this case `release_en` and `release_es`, just use the dot notation to access object properties. Here's your solution.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="r in json">
    <div v-for="x in r.release">
      <p>EN: {{ x.release_en }}</p>
      <p>ES: {{ x.release_es }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  // Other stuff here...

</div>
```